# How do I create luigi dependency graph but do not run anything?

Tags: luigi

Use case: some tasks are long batch jobs that take hours, need to review what completed and what failed for a given date before deciding which date to rerun first.

How to view the dependency graph generated by the central scheduler while not running anything? I do realize that I can simply rerun the graph for a given date and (assuming nothing changed) it will fail at exactly the same place(s) as last run, and I will be able to see the graph in the scheduler. Suppose, a task takes a long time before it fails. Is there something like a `--dry-run` argument?

I could also create an empty "toggle switch" task that would fail or complete based on input argument. However, I would need to remember to make every task depend on it - easy to overlook (can be solved by subclassing) but also creating clutter.

Any better options to consider?

**Edit:**

It looks like I can get what I need by setting `--workers=0` when calling `luigi`. This results in the following message:

```
Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :| because there were tasks that were not granted run permission by the scheduler
```

Nothing was run, and I get my graph. Seems like a useful hack to document here.

Answer (score 3):

Running with `--workers=0` works for normal dependency graphs. However, if you utilize dynamic dependencies, those graph nodes will be ignored (dynamic dependencies are `Tasks` yielded within a `run()`.

A future alternative is a [WIP PR](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/pull/2336) for a Static DAG Visualizer. However, I suspect that dynamic dependencies will still be ignored given the necessity for `run()` execution.